# mysqldump with --quick option crashes mysqld with out of memory

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysqldump

I am trying to dump the mysql database that contains a lot of databases. Most of them are empty/small, and there are only 3 large databases. Two are 10GB each, and another is 40GB.

The tables of these databases (they have the same tables) are small except for one table which contains sent email - email_outgoing_event. This table represents **99%** of the consumed disk of each database.

I tried to dump a single database - the largest one (40GB), and it crashed by reaching the maximum ram(14GB). I am using the following command:

```
mysqldump --quick campaign_401 email_outgoing_event | gzip > dump_401.sql.gz
```

I also tried the following command

```
mysqldump --quick campaign_401 email_outgoing_event --skip-extended-insert | gzip > dump_401.sql.gz
```

In the documentation, it says that --quick should dump the table by getting rows instead of getting the whole database, but in my case, it seems to do nothing - mysqld crashes with `out of memory`.

I tried the above commands with the other two databases (10 GB), and it worked. Which, I am not sure, seems to indicate that I need at least 40GB ram to be able to dump the largest database.

My questions are,

- Is there any solution to dump the database without crashing mysqld? Can cgroups and limiting ram help by not allowing mysqld to consume more memory than X%?
- Why `--quick` option isn't working ?
- Or I am mistaken, and it does something else from what I understood?
- Is there a possibility that --quick option is ignored by our mysql server?

`mysql --version` gives the following result

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Is it possible that this specific version does not understand `--quick` option?

**UPDATE**
As danblack pointed out very well, I was looking in the wrong place. The problem was that the mysqld process allocated max(virt) size of 14.9 GB while the machine had 14GB. By tuning the configuration so that mysqld allocates a max of 12GB (needs more tuning) , mysqldump does not crash the database anymore.

Comment: What is your mysql configuration? It looks like its configured to use more ram than you actually have. mysqldump maybe the trigger, but the underlying problem is the server configuration and its relation to actual memory available.

Comment: @danblack, maybe you are right. Is there any particular configuration/system variable I should look? But also, shouldn't --quick option dump row by row anyway.

Comment: @danblack, now that I changed a little bit configuration, virt memory is less than the available. I remember that previously it allocated more virt memory that the machine had(14,9GB or something like this while the machine had 14GB). I will try dumping again with 12GB limit.

Comment: Please provide your my.cnf file.  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: `--quick` is a confusing term.  And no, it batches thousands of rows together.  Probably a setting can be shrunk to avoid the space needed to build up the strings.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, it seems that mysqldump does not crash anymore after tuning some variables so that mysqld does not allocate more ram than the machine has. I changed  innodb_buffer_pool_size from 12GB to 10GB, and the top command shows virt memory of 12.4GB(needs more tuning). Previously the value was higher than the machine's ram.

Comment: It is generally wise to have _some_ swap space so that, in cases like this, you won't crash (but, instead, slow down).